# Minus sign doesn't appear when hovering over plotly output

Tags: r, ggplot2, plotly

I have created the following plot in R using `plotly`. When I hover my cursor over the bars that are negative, the corresponding percentage label is positive for some odd reason (no minus sign). Has anyone had a similar issue before/a way to fix this

Here is a reproductible of `dataset`

```
structure(list(Date = structure(c(17956, 18048, 18140, 18231, 
18322, 18414, 17956, 18048, 18140, 18231, 18322, 18414), class = "Date"), 
    Key = c("Annual", "Annual", "Annual", "Annual", "Annual", 
    "Annual", "Annualised", "Annualised", "Annualised", "Annualised", 
    "Annualised", "Annualised"), Percent = c(0.05, 1, 0.14, -0.57, 
    -0.22, -17.21, -3.18, 3.31, -0.84, -1.44, -1.81, -51.05)), row.names = c(NA, 
-12L), key = structure(list(Key = c("Annual", "Annualised"), 
    .rows = structure(list(1:6, 7:12), ptype = integer(0), class = c("vctrs_list_of", 
    "vctrs_vctr", "list"))), row.names = 1:2, class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), .drop = TRUE), index = structure("Date", ordered = TRUE), index2 = "Date", interval = structure(list(
    year = 0, quarter = 0, month = 0, week = 0, day = 1, hour = 0, 
    minute = 0, second = 0, millisecond = 0, microsecond = 0, 
    nanosecond = 0, unit = 0), .regular = TRUE, class = c("interval", 
"vctrs_rcrd", "vctrs_vctr")), class = c("tbl_ts", "tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame"))
```

and my code below

```
#Load Packages 

pacman::p_load(tidyverse,lubridate,plotly)

# Set Margin spacing for Plotly

m <- list(
  t = 50,
  b = 30,
  pad = 4
)

# ggplot

p1 <- ggplot(dataset, aes(Date, Percent, fill = Key)) +
  geom_bar(position='dodge', stat='identity') +
  theme_bw() +
  labs(y = '%') +
  geom_hline(yintercept = 0, linetype = 'dashed',col = 'red') +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c('#EFBE93','#75002B')) +
  theme(legend.title = element_blank()) +
  scale_x_date(date_breaks="3 months", date_labels = "%b-%Y") 

## ggplotly

p1 %>% ggplotly(tooltip = c('Date','Percent')) %>% 
  layout(legend = list(orientation = "h", x = 0.35, y = -0.2)) %>% 
  add_annotations(xref='paper',yref='paper',x=1,y=-0.15,text='*Source - Stats SA',showarrow=F,
                  font=list(size=10,color='black')) %>% 
  layout(title = list(text = paste0('Quarterly Growth in South African GDP',
                                    '<br>',
                                    '<sup>',
                                    'There is a sharp contrast between annual and annualised rates recorded for Q2 of this year.',
                                    '</sup>'),x=0.07),margin = m)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @eduardokapp said, this looks like a bug in `ggplotly`.  A workaround is to add another copy of `Percent` to use in the tooltip:

```
dataset$Pct <- dataset$Percent
p1 <- ggplot(dataset, aes(Date, Pct, fill = Key, Percent = Percent)) +
  geom_bar(position='dodge', stat='identity') +
  theme_bw() +
  labs(y = '%') +
  geom_hline(yintercept = 0, linetype = 'dashed',col = 'red') +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c('#EFBE93','#75002B')) +
  theme(legend.title = element_blank()) +
  scale_x_date(date_breaks="3 months", date_labels = "%b-%Y") 
p1 %>% ggplotly(tooltip = c('Date','Percent')) %>% 
  layout(legend = list(orientation = "h", x = 0.35, y = -0.2)) %>% 
  add_annotations(xref='paper',yref='paper',x=1,y=-0.15,text='*Source - Stats SA',showarrow=F,
                  font=list(size=10,color='black')) %>% 
  layout(title = list(text = paste0('Quarterly Growth in South African GDP',
                                    '<br>',
                                    '<sup>',
                                    'There is a sharp contrast between annual and annualised rates recorded for Q2 of this year.',
                                    '</sup>'),x=0.07),margin = m)
```

Answer (score 1):

Apparently this is a bug in `ggplotly()`. See [this issue](https://github.com/ropensci/plotly/issues/874) and [this older one](https://github.com/ropensci/plotly/issues/616). I could not find any explicit solution to this.

The only solution I can think of is explicitly creating your plot using `plotly` directly, instead of `ggplot` --> `ggplotly()`.

Comment: Thanks @eduardokapp ! I went with @user2554330's solution for now but I'll probably just make my plots in ```plotly``` from now on instead!